# Error in read and write client server programming

Tags: client-server

I'm working on a c program in linux. I need to use client server programming. I used read and write and it worked fine. But after using more than 20 read and write in both server and client, it has stopped working. That is I don't receive any output for that. Line. I don't understand what is the problem because am using the very same lines.

```
bzero(&hl,200);
read(a,hl,50*sizeof(char));
printf("%s",hl);
```

In client side,

```
bzero(&hl,200);
strcpy(hl,"hello");
write(a,hl,50*sizeof(char));
printf("%s",hl);
```

Also, am not able to get the return value and print it. While I used it in debian, I got the return value and able to print. Now, am in Ubuntu (at home). It's not printing return value now. No error too! Is it anything to do with OS?

Please help me figure out the problem.

UPDATED:

In server,

int c:
s=read(a,&c,sizeof(int));
printf("choice: %d",c);

In client,

scanf("%d",&ch);
s=write(sd,&ch,sizeof(int));

Both has size 4. But, in client I got garbage value while I print the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You throw away the return value of `read`, so you have no idea how many bytes you've read. What if it's less than 50?

Change:

```
read(a,hl,50*sizeof(char));
```

To:

```
int readBytes = 0;
do
{
    int r = read(a, hl + readBytes, 50 - readBytes);
    if (r <= 0)
        return; // or however you want to handle an error
    readBytes += r;
} while (readBytes < 50);
```

That will ensure you actually read 50 bytes.

You are imagining that TCP somehow "glues" those 50 bytes together. But the system has no idea that those 50 bytes are a message -- only your code does. So it's your code's job to glue them back together. TCP does not preserve application message boundaries -- that is the application's job.

Comment: In client. side am getting 50 bytes and server 40. What I should do now?

Comment: Fix the server so it calls `read` again to get the remaining 10 bytes. Nothing "glues" those 50 bytes together -- your program is the only thing that knows that they're a message, so it's your program's job to glue them back together.

Comment: Still it's the same, Sir. Also, am not able to get the return value and print it. While I used it in debian, I got the return value and able to print. Now, am in Ubuntu (at home). It's not printing return value now. Is it anything to do with OS?

Comment: Paste the code that isn't working. Odds are you're trying to read data when the other side hasn't sent any (or you've already read it all).

Comment: You have to define the protocol at the byte level. How many bytes are you sending? What's the first byte mean? You can't just cast things to pointers and send them and expect it to work. You also, again, fail to check the return value from `read`, so you again have no idea how many bytes you read. Again, you are expecting the TCP implementation to "glue" those bytes together into a message on the receiving side. TCP DOES NOT DO THAT. That's *your* job. And your code doesn't do it.

Comment: I have checked the number of bytes already and added in the question. Sending 4 bytes and receiving 4 bytes. The same code works well in another part of the program and also in a separate client server program. Even further sending and receiving doesn't happen. But in a separate program, they run.

Comment: @Gomathi: Likely it's a similar bug in another part of the code. If any part of the code doesn't read all the bytes that are expected, they'll be "left over" for another part to read. You have to fix everything before you can really expect it to work. If this is your first time using TCP, you might want to reconsider doing something smaller first, and start by documenting the application protocol at the byte level.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. As you said, the problem was with size only. But the funniest part is, the problem was not with this code. The codes above it had it. Thats why this code had worked in other programs.I corrected the size and its working fine. Thanks for spending your valuable time, Sir.